# JavaScript MediaSource and MediaRecorder lag in playing live-stream video

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediarecorder, media-source

I have working on streaming live video using `WebRTC` based on `RTCConnection` with library called `simple-peer`, but I have faced with some lag between live stream video (with `MediaRecorder`) and that was played on using `MediaSource`

Here is recorder:

```js
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    function handleDataAvailable(event) {
      if (connected && event.data.size > 0) {
        peer.send(event.data);
      }
    }
    ...
    peer.on('connect', () => {
      // wait for 'connect' event before using the data channel
      mediaRecorder.start(1);
    });
```

Here is source that is played:

```js
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    var sourceBuffer;
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', args => {
      sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
    });
    ...
    peer.on('data', data => {
      // got a data channel message
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
    });
```

I open two tabs and connect to myself and I see delay in playing video ...
Seems like I configured badly `MediaRecorder` or `MediaSource`

Any help will be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've combined two completely unrelated techniques for streaming the video, and are getting the worst tradeoffs of both.  :-)

WebRTC has media stream handling built into it.  If you expect realtime video, the WebRTC stack is what you want to use.  It handles codec negotiation, auto-scales bandwidth, frame size, frame rate, and encoding parameters to match network conditions, and will outright drop chunks of time to keep playback as realtime as possible.

On the other hand, if retaining quality is more desirable than being realtime, MediaRecorder is what you would use.  It makes no adjustments based on network conditions because it is unaware of those conditions.  MediaRecorder doesn't know or care where you put the data after it gives you the buffers.

If you try to play back video as it's being recorded, will inevitably lag further and further behind because there is no built-in catch-up method.  The only thing that can happen is a buffer underrun, where the playback side waits until there is enough data to begin playback again.  Even if it becomes minutes behind, it isn't going to automatically skip ahead.

The solution is to use the right tool.  It sounds like from your question that you want realtime video.  Therefore, you need to use WebRTC.  Fortunately simple-peer makes this... simple.

On the recording side:

```
const peer = new Peer({
  initiator: true,
  stream
});
```

Then on the playback side:

```
peer.on('stream', (stream) => {
  videoEl.srcObject = stream;
});
```

Much simpler.  The WebRTC stack handles everything for you.

Comment: But I want not only real-time video, but also somehow to share stream from one peer to few other and chunks I need because I want one chunk of stream if some peer do not receive it from me in time maybe this chunk could be sent from near peer that already received it

Comment: @DenisKotov You can't have it both ways.  You can't have simultaneously realtime and not realtime.  How would that work?  You're saying that the issue is that the receiving end is getting too far behind, and yet you say you also want them to stay behind and wait for the video.  What are you asking, specifically, and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want to send video for example two people, but if second person has some issue with connection to me or some other issues, I want that first person that have received video chunk send it to second person, somehow to support live stream from me ... Something like torrents do ;)

Comment: If they're going to forward the data onward, you'll need Media Recorder like you're doing.  But, this isn't going to be realtime... you will always have additional latency, by the very nature of how this will work.  Decentralizing is a great tradeoff for some projects, but you can expect your viewers to be *minutes* behind if you want to use it most efficiently.

Comment: But is there a way to remove this tradeoff ? Actually I've just open two tabs on my PC and there is a big lag ... In this scenario no network lag ...

Comment: Think through what you're asking.  You want video to be played as near realtime as possible.  You also want to ensure that all the video makes it to the viewer.  In between the source and the viewer is the internet... a big unreliable pipe where whatever comes in probably comes out, but in different orders and maybe damaged.  This can be worked around, but requires buffering... delaying.  Therefore, you *must* choose your tradeoffs.  No, you can't have everything, and if you think through it it should be clear to you why.

Comment: Maybe a similar scenario would help.  One person says something into a tape recorder, then mails that tape to 5 friends and tells those 5 friends to make copies and mail those tapes to 5 other friends.  Now 30 listeners have heard the message, but they have all first had to record a tape to do it.  This is analogous to them buffering the data being sent to them.  Now, you can do this in very small chunks... at the packet level, sure.  But, it's more complicated than this simple graph.  Peers will come and go, so you need a way to coordinate them.

Comment: Yes, I want somehow to coordinate users, also I tries to find some method for peer.send like flush but it does not exist ( Advantage of this complicated solution is that system more robust for users with weak internet, packets loss for some users and with other issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218194/discussion-between-denis-kotov-and-brad).